# Merge 2d arrays with same index value

Tags: php

How can I merge one array inside another 2d array based on a unique value that is shared on both 2d array?

Arrays:

```
$arr1 = [
    "First" =>[
        "Name" => "John",
        "Id" => 123
    ],
    "Second" =>[
        "Name" => "Peter",
        "Id" => 45
    ]
];  

$arr2 = [
    "First" =>[
        "Age" => 34,
        "Id" => 123
    ],
    "Second" =>[
        "Age" => 24,
        "Id" => 45
    ]
];

$n = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

Current output when var_dump $n:

```
array(2) {
 ["First"]=>
   array(2) {
    ["Age"]=>
    int(34)
    ["Id"]=>
    int(123)
 }
 ["Second"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Age"]=>
    int(24)
    ["Id"]=>
    int(45)
 }
}
```

Desired output:

```
array(2) {
 ["First"]=>
   array(2) {
    ["Name"]=>
    String("John")
    ["Age"]=>
    int(34)
    ["Id"]=>
    int(123)
 }
 ["Second"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Name"]=>
    String("Peter")
    ["Age"]=>
    int(24)
    ["Id"]=>
    int(45)
 }
}
```

Ofcourse just by merging the two arrays wont fix my issue, but i was just wondering what approach I should take to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this structure of your arrays, you can use [`array_replace_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php).

```
$n = array_replace_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
```

Fiddle: https://3v4l.org/IPGsl

Some people can say that you can use [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive), but no. As you have same key (`Id`) in both arrays, resulting array will have not the structure you expect. But in case you have **different** keys in both arrays - `array_merge_recursive` is an option too.

Comment: you just taught me the difference there. I just saw the duplicate ID's in my own code. Thanks!

Comment: @u_mulder yes I was afraid of asking the question as I thought i will be getting hate by people saying to use array_merge_recursive, but that doesnt work. thanks I think this is what I need, havent really tested on my real code, as the above is just an example, but it seems to be working. thanks